# Segmentation fault found but message before that is being optimized out

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I wrote the following code in GDB online debugger :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("jkjkkjkj");

  int p , n;
  FILE *fp;
  printf("jkjkkjkj2");
  fp = fopen("abc.txt","r");

  while ( (n = getc(fp))!= EOF)
  {
    printf( "the chareacter here is %d \n", n);
  }

  n = fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

While executing the code I am getting a segmentation fault at the line where I am trying to fetch the characters from the file. I know that as the file does not exist the segmentation fault error is coming.

However, what intrigues me is the absence of the messages that I am trying to print on the screen. I tried checking on debugger and once I found:

```
optimized out written near the line no
```

However, I tried putting `getchar()` here and there, the messages got printed on the screen even if the segmentation fault persists.

How to explain this? Why is this happening? Why are the messages printed when I am putting `getchar()` at different places?

I had tried writing this code on a Solaris server and compiling using GCC. The code got compiled but I did not get any output message even when a file with the name provided in the directory existed.

Comment: Regarding the `printf` debugging, you forget that output to `stdout` by default is *line buffered*. Output is buffered until there is a newline. So I suggest you make a habit of always printing a newline at the end of your strings (like `printf("jkjkkjkj\n");`). Output is also flushed when you want to read from `stdin`, those two streams are connected.

Comment: You should have seen the messages when it prints the first `the character here is` line, since that has a newline in it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : Thanks a lot , that worked

Comment: Print error/debug logging output to the unbuffered Standard Error Output: `fprintf(stderr, "%d", 42);` or `fputs("bla", stderr);`

Comment: @Barmar : I cannot because there is segmentation fault at the line when it is trying to read characters just before that printf

Comment: @alk :  Will try that too thanks

Comment: @KanishkViman I meant when you run it on your Solaris system and the file exists.

Comment: @Barmar Probably segfaults even before that, for an unchecked NULL in `fp`.

Comment: @Yunnosch If the file exists, why would he get NULL in fp?

Comment: @Barmar I have seen your condition/assumption. But there IS a segfault and I don't see another way of provoking one. So what makes you believe that the file exists and is readable? Also I wanted to imply that checking for NULL is always a good idea...

Comment: @Barmar :  Yes but  while writing in solaris  i did not put that print message

Comment: If you're talking about a different program, how are we supposed to explain what it does?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : But without segfault i will get those print messages right ?

Comment: You'll get them when the program exits, since that will flush the buffer.

Comment: BTW, you wrote your code in a [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor), not in `gdb`. Then you [compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) your code into some [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable), and you should have shown your compilation command in your question. At last you run that executable with the `gdb` debugger. Terminology is important

Comment: Most likely, the call to `fopen()` is failing: suggest the next code after that statement be: if( !fp ) { perror( "fopen failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `printf("jkjkkjkj2");`  end the format string with '\n' so the system immediately flushes the `stdout` buffer to the terminal

Answer (score 3):

As [answered by Yunnosch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50189308/841108), you probably forgot to check against failure of [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html). A better habit is to *always* check that, at least by coding:

```
  fp = fopen("abc.txt","r"); 
  if (fp == NULL) { perror("fopen abc.txt"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

and take the habit of doing at least that everywhere. Using [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) (or [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) with [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)) is a useful habit to get, since you want some reason related to the failure (given by `errno` perhaps thru `perror`).

More generally, always **read the documentation** of functions that you are using (for standard functions, at least on some [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website, and possibly in the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), and **take care of handling their failure** (at the very least, by checking against failure and exiting with a useful message to `stderr`); for Unix functions, see their `man` pages (on Linux, start on [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) and [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html); for Solaris, start with [intro(2)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29032/intro-2.html#scrolltoc) & [intro(3)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37843/intro-3.html)..). In your Unix terminal, try also `man fopen` ... For POSIX standard, start [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html).

---

> what intrigues me is the absence of the messages that I am trying to print on the screen.

That is simple. *stdout* is buffered (see also [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html)), and often line-buffered. So a `printf` which does not end with a `\n` has its output still inside the buffer, and not yet on the screen. The habit to get is to almost always end your [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) control format string with a newline, or else to flush the buffer explicitly using [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html).

For a newbie, there are few reasons to avoid ending your `printf` with an explicit `\n`. So use instead

```
printf("jkjkkjkj\n");
```

Otherwise, call `fflush(NULL);`  quite often in your program. BTW, for these buffering reasons, `fflush(NULL)` should be done before calls to [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and other important program-wide functions.

---

> optimized out written near the line no

That probably happens in the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) itself (e.g. in `getc` from some `libc.so`), which is usually not compiled with debug information. In practice, trust your C standard library: you are much more likely to have bugs in your code that in `libc`.

Your own source code should be compiled [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (asking the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler to give all warnings and debug info in [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format, usable by the `gdb` debugger) and you need to improve your code to get no warnings at all before [using the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

Be aware of [**undefined behavior**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), spend several hours reading about UB, and be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of UB.

Comment: I did not get the last point of yours . The part where you mention about debug information. Could you please explain a little more ?

Comment: I improved a bit by giving links. Is that enough ?

Answer (score 1):

Try guarding against NULL in `fp` and for good measure make sure the debug output gets printed (as in comment by Some Programmer Dude).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{    
   int p , n;
   FILE *fp;

   printf("jkjkkjkj2\n");
   fp = fopen("abc.txt","r"); 

   if (NULL != fp)
   {
      while ( (n = getc(fp))!= EOF)
      {
           printf( "the chareacter here is %d \n", n);
      }
      n = fclose(fp);
   } else
   { 
       printf("File opening failed somehow!\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Note the nice touch (by Basile Starynkevitch) to only close what was successfully opened.

Comment: `fclose` should be moved, since it should not get called when `fp` is `NULL`