# nested for loops ending sooner than expected

Tags: c, function, for-loop, nested-loops

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void block(int r, char a, char b);

int main(){
  block(2, '+', '-');
}

void block(int r, char a, char b){
  int i;
  char x = a;
  char y = b;
  for (i = 1; i <= r; i++){
    if ( i%2 == 1){
      for (i = 1; i <= r; i++){
        printf("%c", x);
      }
      for (i = 1; i <= r; i++){
        printf("%c", y);
      }
    } else
    {
      for (i = 1; i <= r; i++){
        printf("%c", x);
      }
      for (i = 1; i <= r; i++){
        printf("%c", y);
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return;
}
```

intended output:

```
++--
--++
```

what I get instead:

```
++--
```

Nothing prints after the first line. For instance for r = 5 it prints the first line +++++----- correctly but doesn't print the remaining lines of the solution.

correct solution:

```
+++++-----
-----+++++
+++++-----
-----+++++
+++++-----
```

Comment: You're using the same loop counter for all your loops...

Comment: Because you're reusing `i` in nested loops.

Comment: See also hints from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50189411/841108) answer

Comment: ... and that would be ok in your case if you'd declared the counter locally, inside the `for`.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @rustyx thanks that fixed it.

Comment: As an aspiring programmer, debugging is one of the most important skills you need to learn. The article linked by alk above has some great tips to get you started.

Comment: @rustyx Care to make an answer? Just to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @alk thank you for the useful article, I am going to start on it so that I don't encounter a similar problem again :)

Comment: Also, you're duplicating too much code. You don't need `x` and `y` or loops within `if`-`else` - just swap `a` and `b` for each line and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @rustyx

This ended up doing the trick for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void block(int r, char a, char b);

int main(){
  block(5, '+', '-');
}

void block(int r, char a, char b){
  int i;
  char x = a;
  char y = b;
  for (i = 1; i <= r; i++){
    if ( i%2 == 1){
      int j;
      for (j = 1; j <= r; j++){
        printf("%c", x);
      }
      for (j = 1; j <= r; j++){
        printf("%c", y);
      }
    }
    else{
      int k;
      for (k = 1; k <= r; k++){
        printf("%c", y);
      }
      for (k = 1; k <= r; k++){
        printf("%c", x);
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return;
}
```

giving this result:

```
+++++-----
-----+++++
+++++-----
-----+++++
+++++-----
```

Comment: Please try for some more consistent indentation. The one from the edited question maybe ...